# Typecast em fopen para comparação com NULL

Tags: c

Quando eu faço um fopen, eu sempre uso um if para correção de erro.

Os ponteiros estão declarados em

```
FILE *mestre, *indice;
```

E eu estou usando-o assim

```
if (((mestre = fopen("//home//vitor//Desktop//mestre.bin", "ab"))==NULL) || ((indice = fopen("//home//vitor//Desktop//indice.bin", "ab")==NULL))){ 
                printf("Erro na abertura do arquivo");              
        }
```

Mas sempre recebo este warning:

**"warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast"**

Existe algum typecast que possa tratar isso?

Comment: Sabe que a função `fopen` retorna um ponteiro para a estrutura `FILE` não? De uma olhada na documentação: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fopen.html. Talvez esteja confundindo com a função `open` da `fcntl.h` que retorna o `File Descriptor`(http://gd.tuwien.ac.at/languages/c/programming-bbrown/c_075.htm).

Comment: Sim, eu só esqueci de comentar ali, o mestre e indice estão declarados como FILE *mestre, *indice  e recebendo corretamente o file, só gostaria de saber o porque do warning. inclusive na documentação tem um exemplo do que eu estou fazendo , no final em opening a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o problema é na forma como você colocou parêntesis na expressão.
Fiz um código com várias combinações de atribuição, o problema no seu caso é que a segunda parte da expressão ficou `indice = fopen(...) == NULL` e não `(indice = fopen(...)) == NULL`.

Logo por prioridade, sua  expressão seria igual a `indice = (fopen(...) == NULL)`. E ai, você está atribuindo um valor inteiro ao ponteiro para a estrutura `FILE`, gerando o erro.

Abaixo segue o código testado:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE* mestre, *indice;

    mestre = fopen("//home//vitor//Desktop//mestre.bin", "ab");
    indice = fopen("//home//vitor//Desktop//indice.bin", "ab");

    if (mestre == NULL || indice == NULL){ 
        printf("Erro na abertura do arquivo");
    }

    if((mestre = fopen("//home//vitor//Desktop//mestre.bin", "ab")) == NULL) {
        printf("Erro na abertura do arquivo");
    }

    if(((mestre = fopen("//home//vitor//Desktop//mestre.bin", "ab")) == NULL) ||
    ((indice = fopen("//home//vitor//Desktop//indice.bin", "ab")) == NULL)) {
        printf("Erro na abertura do arquivo");
    }

    if (((mestre = fopen("//home//vitor//Desktop//mestre.bin", "ab"))==NULL) ||
       ((indice = fopen("//home//vitor//Desktop//indice.bin", "ab")==NULL))){ 
             printf("Erro na abertura do arquivo");              
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Poxa vida, muito obrigado. Eu não tinha me atentado a este detalhe mesmo.

Answer (score 2):

Você perdeu um parênteses. A mensagem informada pelo Clang é um pouco mais clara:

> **k.c:6:86: warning:** incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to
>         `FILE *` (aka `struct _IO_FILE *`) from `int` [`-Wint-conversion`]
>
> ```
> ...|| ((indice = fopen("//home//vitor//Desktop//indice.bin", "ab")==NULL))){ 
>                ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```
>
> **1 warning generated.**

Observe a expressão:

```
((a = fopen(...) == NULL))   // Em C, boleanos são int
```

Imagino que deveria ser:

```
((a = fopen(...)) == NULL)
```